# On hover main image, width is not applying on zoom image please refer my attached image below

Tags: javascript, html, css

On hover main image, the zoom image should display its properties like the specified width and height. Code is working but, the problem in zoom image on hover main image.

```js
/* This is my script. I have used this for my code in this, marksize indicates id="mark" in my html main image and zoomImg indicates width and height for on hover the main image. */

$(function(){ 
  $("#show").simpleZoom({
    zoomBox : "#zoom",
    markSize : \[120, 169\],
    zoomSize : \[800, 400\],
    zoomImg : \[480, 677\]
  });
});
            
(function($){
             $.fn.simpleZoom = function(options){
              var defs = {
                                    markSize : \[200, 100\],  
               zoomSize : \[400, 400\],  
               zoomImg : \[800, 800\]   
              };
              var opt = $.fn.extend({}, defs, options);
              return this.each(function(){
               var markBox = $(this);
               var zoomBox = $(opt.zoomBox);
               var zoom_img = $(opt.zoomBox).find("img"); 
               var markBoxSize = \[markBox.width(), markBox.height(), markBox.offset().left, markBox.offset().top\];
               var markSize = opt.markSize;
               var zoomSize = opt.zoomSize;
               var zoomImg = opt.zoomImg;
               var mark_ele = "<i id='mark'></i>";
               var mark_css = {position:"absolute", top:0, left:0, width:markSize\[0\]+"px", height:markSize\[1\]+"px", backgroundColor:"#000", opacity:.5, filter:"alpha(opacity=50)",  display:"none", cursor:"crosshair"};
               
               var show_w = markBoxSize\[0\]-markSize\[0\];
               var show_h = markBoxSize\[1\]-markSize\[1\];
            
               //created mark element and add cascading style sheets
               zoomBox.css({width:zoomSize\[0\]+"px", height:zoomSize\[1\]+"px"});
               markBox.append(mark_ele);
               $("#mark").css(mark_css);
            
               markBox.mouseover(function(){
                $("#mark").show();
                zoomBox.show();
               }).mouseout(function(){
                $("#mark").hide();
                zoomBox.hide();
               }).mousemove(function(e){
                var l = e.pageX-markBoxSize\[2\]-(markSize\[0\]/2);
                var t = e.pageY-markBoxSize\[3\]-(markSize\[1\]/2);
                if(l < 0){
                 l = 0;
                }else if(l > show_w){
                 l = show_w;
                }
                if(t < 0){
                 t = 0;
                }else if(t > show_h){
                 t = show_h;
                }
                $("#mark").css({left:l+"px", top:t+"px"});    
                var z_x = -(l/show_w)*(zoomImg\[0\]-zoomSize\[0\]);
                var z_y = -(t/show_h)*(zoomImg\[1\]-zoomSize\[1\]);
                zoom_img.css({left:z_x+"px", top:z_y+"px"});
               });
              });
             }
})(jQuery);
```

```css
#show {
  width: 100%;
  height: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  left: 0;
}
#show_mark {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: .5;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  cursor: crosshair;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  display: none;
}
#zoom {
  position: absolute;
  left: 250px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99;
  /*width: 400px;*/
  height: 400px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
}
#zoom img {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#show_pic{
  display: block !important;
  width: 60% !important;
  height: 400px !important;
  margin: 0 0 0 21%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div id="show">
    <img src="<?php echo 'data:image;base64,'.$productimage; ?>" id="show_pic" />
  </div>
  <div id="zoom">
    <img src="<?php echo 'data:image;base64,'.$productimage; ?>"/> 
  </div>
</div>
```

The above shown is my image. Please refer and help me out soon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Instead of the above code i have done with this and it's working fine.
```

**HTML code**

```
 <div class="bzoom_wrap">
        <ul id="bzoom">
            <li>
                <img class="bzoom_thumb_image" src="saree.jpeg" />
                <img class="bzoom_big_image" src="saree.jpeg"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="bzoom_thumb_image" src="saree1.jpeg"/>
                <img class="bzoom_big_image" src="saree1.jpeg"/>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img class="bzoom_thumb_image" src="saree2.jpeg"/>
                <img class="bzoom_big_image" src="saree2.jpeg"/>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**Scripts i have used**

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#bzoom").zoom({
            zoom_area_width: 400,
            autoplay_interval: 3000,
            small_thumbs: 3,
            autoplay: false
        });
    </script>

    <script>

        (function ($) {
            $.fn.zoom = function (options) {

                var _option = {
                    align: "left",
                    thumb_image_width: 380,
                    thumb_image_height: 400,
                    source_image_width: 450,
                    source_image_height: 450,
                    zoom_area_width: 400,
                    zoom_area_height: "justify",
                    zoom_area_distance: 10,
                    zoom_easing: true,
                    click_to_zoom: false,
                    zoom_element: "auto",
                    show_descriptions: true,
                    description_location: "bottom",
                    description_opacity: 0.7,
                    small_thumbs: 3,
                    smallthumb_inactive_opacity: 1,
                    smallthumb_hide_single: true,
                    smallthumb_select_on_hover: false,
                    smallthumbs_position: "bottom",
                    show_icon: true,
                    hide_cursor: false,
                    //          speed: 600,                 
                    autoplay: true,
                    //          autoplay_interval: 6000,    
                    keyboard: true,
                    right_to_left: false,
                }

                if (options) {
                    $.extend(_option, options);
                }

                var $ul = $(this);
                if ($ul.is("ul") && $ul.children("li").length && $ul.find(".bzoom_big_image").length) {

                    $ul.addClass('bzoom clearfix').show();
                    var $li = $ul.children("li").addClass("bzoom_thumb"),
                            li_len = $li.length,
                            autoplay = _option.autoplay;
                    $li.first().addClass("bzoom_thumb_active").show();
                    if (li_len < 2) {
                        autoplay = false;
                    }

                    $ul.find(".bzoom_thumb_image").css({width: _option.thumb_image_width, height: _option.thumb_image_height}).show();

                    var scalex = _option.thumb_image_width / _option.source_image_width,
                            scaley = _option.thumb_image_height / _option.source_image_height,
                            scxy = _option.thumb_image_width / _option.thumb_image_height;

                    var $bzoom_magnifier, $bzoom_magnifier_img, $bzoom_zoom_area, $bzoom_zoom_img;


                    if (!$(".bzoom_magnifier").length) {
                        $bzoom_magnifier = $('<li class="bzoom_magnifier"><div class=""><img src="" /></div></li>');
                        $bzoom_magnifier_img = $bzoom_magnifier.find('img');

                        $ul.append($bzoom_magnifier);

                        $bzoom_magnifier.css({top: top, left: left});
                        $bzoom_magnifier_img.attr('src', $ul.find('.bzoom_thumb_active .bzoom_thumb_image').attr('src')).css({width: _option.thumb_image_width, height: _option.thumb_image_height});
                        $bzoom_magnifier.find('div').css({width: _option.thumb_image_width * scalex, height: _option.thumb_image_height * scaley});
                    }


                    if (!$('.bzoom_zoom_area').length) {
                        $bzoom_zoom_area = $('<li class="bzoom_zoom_area"><div><img class="bzoom_zoom_img" /></div></li>');
                        $bzoom_zoom_img = $bzoom_zoom_area.find('.bzoom_zoom_img');
                        var top = 0,
                                left = 0;

                        $ul.append($bzoom_zoom_area);

                        if (_option.align == "left") {
                            top = 0;
                            left = 0 + _option.thumb_image_width + _option.zoom_area_distance;
                        }

                        $bzoom_zoom_area.css({top: top, left: left});
                        $bzoom_zoom_img.css({width: _option.source_image_width, height: _option.source_image_height});
                    }

                    var autoPlay = {
                        autotime: null,
                        isplay: autoplay,
                        start: function () {
                            if (this.isplay && !this.autotime) {
                                this.autotime = setInterval(function () {
                                    var index = $ul.find('.bzoom_thumb_active').index();
                                    changeLi((index + 1) % _option.small_thumbs);
                                }, _option.autoplay_interval);
                            }
                        },
                        stop: function () {
                            clearInterval(this.autotime);
                            this.autotime = null;
                        },
                        restart: function () {
                            this.stop();
                            this.start();
                        }
                    }


                    var $small = '';
                    if (!$(".bzoom_small_thumbs").length) {
                        var top = _option.thumb_image_height + 10,
                                width = _option.thumb_image_width,
                                smwidth = (_option.thumb_image_width / _option.small_thumbs) - 10,
                                smheight = smwidth / scxy,
                                ulwidth =
                                smurl = '',
                                html = '';

                        for (var i = 0; i < _option.small_thumbs; i++) {
                            smurl = $li.eq(i).find('.bzoom_thumb_image').attr("src");

                            if (i == 0) {
                                html += '<li class="bzoom_smallthumb_active"><img src="' + smurl + '" alt="small" style="width:' + smwidth + 'px; height:' + smheight + 'px;" /></li>';
                            } else {
                                html += '<li style="opacity:1;"><img src="' + smurl + '" alt="small" style="width:' + smwidth + 'px; height:' + smheight + 'px;" /></li>';
                            }
                        }

                        $small = $('<li class="bzoom_small_thumbs" style="top:' + top + 'px; width:' + width + 'px;"><ul class="clearfix" style="width: 485px;">' + html + '</ul></li>');
                        $ul.append($small);

                        $small.delegate("li", "click", function (event) {
                            changeLi($(this).index());
                            autoPlay.restart();
                        });

                        autoPlay.start();
                    }

                    function changeLi(index) {
                        $ul.find('.bzoom_thumb_active').removeClass('bzoom_thumb_active').stop().animate({opacity: 0}, _option.speed, function () {
                            $(this).hide();
                        });
                        $small.find('.bzoom_smallthumb_active').removeClass('bzoom_smallthumb_active').stop().animate({opacity: _option.smallthumb_inactive_opacity}, _option.speed);

                        $li.eq(index).addClass('bzoom_thumb_active').show().stop().css({opacity: 0}).animate({opacity: 1}, _option.speed);
                        $small.find('li:eq(' + index + ')').addClass('bzoom_smallthumb_active').show().stop().css({opacity: _option.smallthumb_inactive_opacity}).animate({opacity: 1}, _option.speed);

                        $bzoom_magnifier_img.attr("src", $li.eq(index).find('.bzoom_thumb_image').attr("src"));
                    }




                    _option.zoom_area_height = _option.zoom_area_width / scxy;
                    $bzoom_zoom_area.find('div').css({width: _option.zoom_area_width, height: _option.zoom_area_height});

                    $li.add($bzoom_magnifier).mousemove(function (event) {
                        var xpos = event.pageX - $ul.offset().left,
                                ypos = event.pageY - $ul.offset().top,
                                magwidth = _option.thumb_image_width * scalex,
                                magheight = _option.thumb_image_height * scalex,
                                magx = 0,
                                magy = 0,
                                bigposx = 0,
                                bigposy = 0;

                        if (xpos < _option.thumb_image_width / 2) {
                            magx = xpos > magwidth / 2 ? xpos - magwidth / 2 : 0;
                        } else {
                            magx = xpos + magwidth / 2 > _option.thumb_image_width ? _option.thumb_image_width - magwidth : xpos - magwidth / 2;
                        }
                        if (ypos < _option.thumb_image_height / 2) {
                            magy = ypos > magheight / 2 ? ypos - magheight / 2 : 0;
                        } else {
                            magy = ypos + magheight / 2 > _option.thumb_image_height ? _option.thumb_image_height - magheight : ypos - magheight / 2;
                        }

                        bigposx = magx / scalex;
                        bigposy = magy / scaley;

                        $bzoom_magnifier.css({'left': magx, 'top': magy});
                        $bzoom_magnifier_img.css({'left': -magx, 'top': -magy});

                        $bzoom_zoom_img.css({'left': -bigposx, 'top': -bigposy});
                    }).mouseenter(function (event) {
                        autoPlay.stop();

                        $bzoom_zoom_img.attr("src", $(this).find('.bzoom_big_image').attr('src'));
                        $bzoom_zoom_area.css({"background-image": "none"}).stop().fadeIn(400);

                        $ul.find('.bzoom_thumb_active').stop().animate({'opacity': 0.5}, _option.speed * 0.7);
                        $bzoom_magnifier.stop().animate({'opacity': 1}, _option.speed * 0.7).show();
                    }).mouseleave(function (event) {
                        $bzoom_zoom_area.stop().fadeOut(400);
                        $ul.find('.bzoom_thumb_active').stop().animate({'opacity': 1}, _option.speed * 0.7);
                        $bzoom_magnifier.stop().animate({'opacity': 0}, _option.speed * 0.7, function () {
                            $(this).hide();
                        });

                        autoPlay.start();
                    })
                }
            }
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
```

**My style sheet**

```
<style>
    .bzoom { direction: ltr; }
    .bzoom,
    .bzoom_thumb,
    .bzoom_thumb_image,
    .bzoom_big_image,
    .bzoom_zoom_preview,
    .bzoom_icon,
    .bzoom_hint { display: none }
    .bzoom,
    .bzoom ul,
    .bzoom li,
    .bzoom img,
    .bzoom_hint,
    .bzoom_icon,
    .bzoom_description {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        border: 0;
        list-style: none;
    }

    .bzoom,
    .bzoom_magnifier div,
    .bzoom_magnifier div img,
    .bzoom_small_thumbs ul,
    ul .bzoom_small_thumbs li,
    .bzoom_zoom_area div,
    .bzoom_zoom_img { position: relative; }

    .bzoom img,
    .bzoom li {
        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -khtml-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: none;
        -o-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;
        -webkit-user-drag: none;
        -moz-user-drag: none;
        user-drag: none;
    }

    .bzoom,
    .bzoom_small_thumbs li { float: left; }

    .bzoom_right { float: right;}

    .bzoom li { 
        position: absolute;
        border: 1px solid #cfcece;

    }

    .bzoom img {
        vertical-align: bottom;
        width: 50px;
        height: 70px;
        border: 1px solid #eaeaea;
    }

    .bzoom .bzoom_zoom_area,
    .bzoom_zoom_area {
        background: #fff url(./img/loading.gif) center no-repeat;
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        padding: 6px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ddd;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ddd;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ddd;
        display: none;
        z-index: 20;
    }

    .bzoom_zoom_area div { overflow: hidden; }

    .bzoom_zoom_area .bzoom_zoom_img { position: absolute; }

    .bzoom_wrap .bzoom_magnifier {
        background: #fff;
        outline: #bbb solid 1px;
        display: none;
        cursor: move;
    }

    .bzoom_magnifier div { overflow: hidden; }

    .bzoom_wrap .bzoom_small_thumbs { overflow: hidden; }

    .bzoom_wrap .bzoom_small_thumbs li {
        border: 1px solid #FFF;
        margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid #cfcece;
    }

    .bzoom_wrap ul li.bzoom_smallthumb_active {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ddd;
        -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ddd;
        box-shadow: 0 0 10px #ddd;
        border: 1px solid #535353;
    }

</style>
```